# How can I find two colored object using opencv+python+picamera

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection

I'm using python with opencv installed and picamera.
I need to find 2 green objects from the livestream video from picamera. 
Those objects must be automatically and  there should be a rectangular area around them. Then I need to measure number of colored and black pixels.
Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Hello! I think your question is a bit too broad. Have you tried anything?

Comment: Add details, example input, example expected output (so far this is very vague). What research have you done? What code have you written so far? What are the exact problems that hold you back? | So far the only question I see is whether someone knows how to do it... that information doesn't seem very useful. Perhaps you're after something more specific?